# Memory leak in CLucene

Tags: c++, lucene

I am using CLucene for creating indexing and searching. The index files created are of more than 5 GB. I have Created the seperate dll for CLucene search.
DLL constructor contains the following code

```
lucene::index::IndexReader ptrIndexReader;
lucene::search::IndexSearcher searcher; these are defined in class decalaration/

ptrIndexReader = IndexReader::open(pDir.c_str(),false,NULL);
searcher = new IndexSearcher(ptrIndexReader);
```

I use one search function whose code is as follows

```
bool LuceneWrapper::SearchIndex(wstring somevalue)
{
    lucene::analysis::KeywordAnalyzer fAnalyzer;

    Document doc = NULL;

    Hits hits = NULL;

    Query f_objQuery = NULL;

    NistRecord *f_objRecords = NULL;

    bool flag = false;

    try{
       if (ptrIndexReader == NULL)
       {
          return NULL;
       }
       // Initialize IndexSearcher
       wstring strQuery = _T("+somename:") + somevalue;
       // Initialize Query Parser, with Keyword Analyzer

       QueryParser *parser = new QueryParser( _T(""),&fAnalyzer);
       // Parse Query string

       f_objQuery = parser->parse(strQuery.c_str());
       // Search Index directory

       hits = searcher->search(f_objQuery);

       //searcher.

       int intHitCount =   0;
       intHitCount  = hits->length; 

       if(intHitCount > 0)
       {    
           if(doc!=NULL)
              delete [] doc;
           flag =  true;
       }

       //searcher.close();
  }
  catch(CLuceneError& objExp)
  {
      if(doc!=NULL)
          delete  doc;
      return false;
  }

  if(hits!=NULL)
      delete hits;

  if(f_objQuery!=NULL)
      delete f_objQuery;

  return flag ;
}
```

I am searching very large number of values. according to the record count the main memory goes high and high and at on level it goes near to 2 GB and application crashes. Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this? Why is memory going so high and application crashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never deallocate `parser`.

I can't see a reason to allocate it dynamically.
Why don't you just say

```
 QueryParser parser( _T(""), &fAnalyzer);
 f_objQuery = parser.parse(strQuery.c_str());
```

You also need to make sure that you delete both `f_objQuery` and `hits` in the event of an exception.
`std::unique_ptr` can help you here, if you have access to it.

(And you don't have to test for NULL so much - it's OK to `delete` a null pointer.)